# javascript snackbar image and text loop

Tags: javascript, html

so i'm pulling my hair out because im still noob at Javascript and i have this function:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var y = 0
    var z = 3
    var array1 = ["Wygraj", "przegraj", "Wygraj figę z makiem", "z pasternakiem" ]
    var array2 = ["img/omni_not.png", "img/notify_rainbow.png", "img/notify_fisheye.jpg", "img/notify_square.jpg"]
    document.getElementById("notify_text").innerHTML= array1[y]
    document.getElementById("notify_photo").src = array2[y]
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}

function button_not() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
  x.className = ""
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>
<p>Snackbars are often used as a tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen.</p>
<p>Click on the button to show the snackbar. It will disappear after 3 seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

<div id="snackbar">
  <img src="" class="omni_not" id="notify_photo">
  <p id="notify_text"></p>
  <button type="button" id="close_not" onclick="button_not()"> click me! </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var y = 0
    var z = 3
    var array1 = ["Wygraj", "przegraj", "Wygraj figę z makiem", "z pasternakiem" ]
    var array2 = ["img/omni_not.png", "img/notify_rainbow.png", "img/notify_fisheye.jpg", "img/notify_square.jpg"]
    document.getElementById("notify_text").innerHTML= array1[y]
    document.getElementById("notify_photo").src = array2[y]
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}

function button_not() {
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
  x.className = ""
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What i want to do is change the source of the image and the text every time i call on the snackbar via the button but no matter which loop i try to fit in it gives me syntax error or just doesn't work without any errors. i bet that the resolution is simple but no matter which snippet i used from here it didn't work the way i wanted it to so i'm asking for help here.Also i don't know why but when i wanted to assign to z the array.length attribute and the console said it cannot interpret it.

To sum up i basically want to just increase the value of y by 1 every time button is pressed to get data from both arrays until the index number runs out and make it come back to 0, i know it's stupiditly simple but im just stuck and don't know what to do

Comment: y will always be set to 0 also where are your semicolons???? They are and are not optional in JavaScript. You'll get pretty obscure bugs not always putting them.

Comment: thanks , i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable and increase it by 1. But as it's value will be more than 3, the `text` & `img` will be undefined.For that put a check condition using `if`

```js
var count = -1

function myFunction(num) {
  var array1 = ["Wygraj", "przegraj", "Wygraj figę z makiem", "z pasternakiem"]
  var array2 = ["img/omni_not.png", "img/notify_rainbow.png", "img/notify_fisheye.jpg", "img/notify_square.jpg"]
  document.getElementById("notify_text").innerHTML = array1[num]
  document.getElementById("notify_photo").src = array2[num]
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
  x.className = "show";
  setTimeout(function() {
    x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
  }, 3000);
}

function button_not() {
  //var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1

  count = count + 1;

  myFunction(count)
}
```

```html
<h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>
<p>Snackbars are often used as a tooltips/popups to show a message at the bottom of the screen.</p>
<p>Click on the button to show the snackbar. It will disappear after 3 seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Snackbar</button>

<div id="snackbar">
  <img src="" class="omni_not" id="notify_photo">
  <p id="notify_text"></p>
  <button type="button" id="close_not" onclick="button_not()"> click me! </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be in a closure not a global.